# Meteor run android CordovaError: Requirements check failed

Tags: android, meteor, mobile

I get this error while running in Android using `meteor run android`:

> [CordovaError: Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8 or greater]
>      name: 'CordovaError',
>      message: 'Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8 or greater'

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 32bit, Meteor 1.5.2.1

```
$ java --version
java version "1.8.0_144"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_144-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 25.144-b01, mixed mode)
```

Comment: What does `java --version` show?

Comment: java version "1.8.0_144"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_144-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 25.144-b01, mixed mode)

Comment: Also, execute `echo $JAVA_HOME` in your shell and show its result

Comment: /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_144

Comment: And `echo $PATH` as well

Comment: /home/asman/Android/Sdk/platform-tools:/home/asman/Android/Sdk/tools:/home/asman/.local/share/umake/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/bin:/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_144/bin

Comment: Strange. Seems like all right. What does `cordova requirements` show?

Comment: What means "cordova requirements" is it a command?